# Firebase multiple projects not using correct instance

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Working within Cloud Functions, I'm initialising two projects via the admin SDK as per [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-multiple-apps).

```
// Initialize the default app
admin.initializeApp(defaultAppConfig);

// Initialize another app with a different config
const otherApp = admin.initializeApp(otherAppConfig, 'other');
```

If I log out `otherApp`, it shows the correct FirebaseApp with the name `other`. However, when calling a function on it like this:

```
otherApp.firestore().collection("posts").get()
```

I get results from the default firebase project.

What could be causing this to happen?

Comment: There's not enough information here to diagnose the issue.  We can't see what your configs are in either case, nor can we see your data in each project.  It's entirely possible there's a bug in the SDK as well.  If you think there's a bug, then I suggest posting your **full** reproduction steps to the SDK's GitHub.  https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore

Comment: Answered below. It wasn't a bug. The init call was just not formatted correctly. Thanks for checking it out anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Turns the `otherAppConfig` wasn't formatted correctly. It only contained the JSON serviceAccount data. Needed to format as per the example and add a databaseURL. Silly mistake.

```
const otherApp = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(otherAppConfig),
  databaseURL: "https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com"
}, 'other');
```